# php удалить в строке все кроме, цифр, пробелов и запятых

Tags: php

Это возможно сделать? Если возможно то подскажите как?

Answer (score 0):

Регулярным выражением

```
$str = 'April 15, 2003';
$str = preg_replace('/[^0-9 ,]/', '', $str);
echo $str;  // 15 2003
```

Comment: так он все удалил

Comment: я сделал так, preg_replace('/[^0-9 , \(\)-:]/', но он пробелы удаляет и точки оставляет

Comment: @zoinx2012 ну логично что теперь проблема в вашей модификации.

Comment: @zoinx2012 $str = preg_replace('/[^0-9 ,:()-]/', '', $str);

Comment: @zoinx2012 Ничего подобного. Код удаляет ровно то, что вы попросили `все кроме, цифр, пробелов и запятых` https://ideone.com/M8bTw1

Comment: неа, у меня он только цифры оставил

Comment: @zoinx2012 Я привел ссылку на работающий код. Ищите, что вы изменили в моем коде